# How I can add data-icon attribute in select option using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize

UPD.

before modify

```
dataIcon: " @/images/flag-ukraine.svg"
```

after  modify

```
dataIcon: require("@/assets/svg/flag-ukraine.svg"),
```

difference in **require()**

I have materializecss select
When I addd in dataIcon url "http...." code is worked, but then I try add local file then nothing works.
How do i specify the path to local files?

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
          <select ref="selectCategory" class="icons">
            <option
              v-for="lang in languages"
              :key="lang.id"
              :value="lang.langI"
              :data-icon="lang.dataIcon"
            >{{lang.lang}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

**this is data**

```
data: () => ({
    date: new Date(),
    interval: null,
    dropdown: null,
    languages: [
      {
        lang: "Українська",
        langId: "uk-UA",
        dataIcon:
          " @/images/flag-ukraine.svg"
      },
      {
        lang: "English",
        langId: "en-US",
        dataIcon:
          "https://images.ua.prom.st/1440764527_saharnaya-kartinka-lyubov.jpg"
      }
    ]
  })
```

https://prnt.sc/tb3ept

[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMxqd.png)
[Empty image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbUEO.png)

Comment: Can you show the folder structure? So we can identify whether your local path is correct or not.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tb3ept

Comment: @ОлександрСалівон Please take a look into the official documentation, it will help you to understand how to organize project's structure. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-index-file

Comment: @Yaroslav I read everything that is written there, but nothing will help. Can you tell me how to do it? I added the file structure.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoul keep all your static files in `src/assets/`.
For example if you wont use svg you can create folder with your svg files and after use some of file in your code or html template.

**EDITED:**

```
data: () => ({
date: new Date(),
interval: null,
dropdown: null,
languages: [
  {
    lang: "Українська",
    langId: "uk-UA",
    dataIcon: require("@/assets/svg/flag-ukraine.svg"),
  },
  {
    lang: "English",
    langId: "en-US",
    dataIcon:
      "https://images.ua.prom.st/1440764527_saharnaya-kartinka-lyubov.jpg"
  }
]
  })
```

You have very strange structure of folders. By default and recommended vue js documentation is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKAFO.png)

Comment: I tried your option but it doesn't work? How is it different from mine other than the file path?

Comment: maybe @ path not work in your project.
You can tried set path like this: `../../assets` it depend on wich level is your file in structure

Comment: Or you can store your file in public folder like this example https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-night-i6rxi?file=/src/App.vue
But If we move our images into the public folder, and use the code from above with the new folder reference (/public/doggo/${selectedDog.toLowercase()}.jpg), “it works”. But it is not optimal and I really would not recommend that workaround. The difference between the two folders assets and public/static, and the reason why the first attempt failed, is Webpack.

Comment: Or try this https://codesandbox.io/s/ykx164y2w1?file=/src/App.vue
it should work well